# Varchar to Numeric conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

I have this simple query (SQL Server database) below and I'm not sure why I'm getting an error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

All the data types are `decimal`. Is my conversion incorrect? Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT                  
    RTRIM(year_time) AS year_time ,
    actual = CASE actual
                  WHEN '.00' THEN 0
                  WHEN '' THEN 0
                  ELSE CAST(actual AS NUMERIC(18, 2))
             END ,
    end_balance = CASE end_balance
                       WHEN '.00' THEN 0
                       WHEN '' THEN 0
                       ELSE CAST(end_balance AS NUMERIC(18, 2))
                  END ,
    RTRIM(fund_code) AS fund_code ,
    RTRIM(function_code) AS function_code ,
    RTRIM(object_code) AS object_code ,
    RTRIM(source_code) AS source_code ,
    RTRIM(balance_sheet_code) AS balance_sheet_code
FROM    
    dbo.raw_ledger WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: What exact database system (and which version) are you using? SQL is only the query language - used by many databases- that doesn't really tell us what **database product** (MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? Oracle? SQL Server? Firebird?) you're using

Comment: Try only doing one column at a time until you find the problematic column

Comment: Does your database software have an `IsNumeric()` function?

Comment: Obviously some values in ACTUAL or END_BALANCE contain characters that cannot be converted to numbers.

Comment: Both tables have the same issue and yes there is a isnumeric() function

Comment: Are you sure that you only have numeric values in your columns?  You would solve this problem if you stored the data as the correct datatype.

Comment: mustaccio i think that to be the case but was unsure how to troubleshoot to find the characters

Comment: I edited original post.  Data types are decimal.

Comment: If your datatypes are decimal, why the string comparisons?  There will be an implicit cast on the string types to do the comparison.

Comment: This script was part of a larger process used across multiple templates and it looks like the database--> table that was used had the columns in question already converted to decimal when in prior processes it was varchar.  My oversight.  Thanks Paddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that `actual` and `end_balance` really are strings (I can't see any other obvious reason you would get the error you are getting).  You would use the `isnumeric()` function like this:

```
actual = CASE actual
              WHEN '.00' THEN 0
              WHEN '' THEN 0
              when isnumeric(actual) = 1 then CAST(actual AS NUMERIC(18, 2))
         END ,
end_balance = CASE end_balance
                   WHEN '.00' THEN 0
                   WHEN '' THEN 0
                   when isnumeric(end_balance) = 1 then  CAST(end_balance AS NUMERIC(18, 2))
              END ,
```

This returns NULL if the value is not numeric, but it should prevent your error.